# Is there a way to reset the perspective in Eclipse and avoid the dialog that confirms it?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there a way to reset the perspective in Eclipse and avoid the dialog that confirms it?  I often reset my layout and map this action to a set of keys.  It would be great if I can reset the perspective without it asking me "ARE YOU SURE" every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [current implementation](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/handlers/ResetPerspectiveHandler.java) always shows the confirmation dialog. You have to implement your own command that calls [IWorkbenchPage.html#resetPerspective()](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/rtopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage.html#resetPerspective--).